# Why (the heck) did Tianwan-1 insert into a low inclination orbit then execute a plane change from 11.8 to 86.9 degrees?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, mars, orbital-maneuver, tianwen-1, cnsa

eoPortal's [Tianwen-1 (China's first Mars Exploration Mission)](https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/t/tianwen-1) shows the following graphic, caption and link.

It's often discussed that orbital plane changes are like certain table wines in that they are for [lying down and avoiding](https://montypython.net/scripts/austwine.php). They are generally costly in delta-v. The image shows that the maneuver is likely done at the apoapsis of a 400 x 180,000 km orbit and so the cost has been minimized. At that distance the orbital velocity around Mars is only about <s>485 m/s</s> [97 m/s](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/50795/why-the-heck-did-tianwan-1-insert-into-a-low-inclination-orbit-then-execute-a?noredirect=1#comment165715_50795) and so at least several <s>hundred</s> tens of m/s of delta-v would be needed for such a large plane change.

**Question:** Why not enter directly into a high inclination orbit? From Earth wouldn't it just mean aiming a few thousand km higher at a distance of hundreds of millions of km? This plane change seems unnecessary and a bit costly to me at first glance (a bit of delta-v and an extra burn and maneuver).

[image: Tianwen-1 orbital activity at Mars]

> Figure 10: Planned orbital trajectory at Mars. A scheme of the different orbits that the Chinese probe Tianwen-1 will use around Mars, with informations on the orbital parameters of each of them<sup>13</sup>
>
> <sup>13</sup>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Orbital_trajectory_of_Tianwen-1_around_Mars.png

Comment: [Apoapsis velocity is only 97 m/s](https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/orbital-velocity) (485 m/s would be for a *circular* orbit at 140,000 km), so the [plane change cost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_inclination_change#Calculation) works out to only around 118 m/s. That doesn't answer your question as to why they don't go direct to polar, of course.

Comment: @RussellBorogove yikes, yes. Duly noted and now reaching for more coffee... (as usual)

Comment: Interesting! I didn't imagine plane-change maneuvers could be so cheap in delta-v, but it makes sense at those altitudes. Any numbers on the delta-v cost at 400 km? It would have to be super expensive then, yes?

Comment: (Meant 180,000km, not 140,000, also clearly coffee deprived.) At 400km periapsis, the orbital speed is ~4700 m/s, so the plane change cost would be proportionally increased (I think?) to about 5700 m/s -- not a recommended strategy. In general, for large plane changes, you usually want to raise apoapsis, make the change, and then get to your final periapsis/apoapsis, and for plane changes above 60º in particular, you want to raise apoapsis as high as possible.

Comment: In order to go nearly polar, you need to aim above or below mars (depending in which way you'd want to orbit). If your insertion maneuver fails while you are in-plane, you might be able to salvage a mission because you are in an heliocentric orbit in the plane of mars. if you go above/below, and the insertion fails, you get a gravity assist boosting you completely out of the plane of the solar system, making any kind of salvaged mission nearly impossible. I don't know if that was a consideration, but to me capturing near-plane seems much safer than capturing directly to a highly inclined orbit

Comment: @Polygnome Interesting, but I'm not sure it's *actually and demonstrably* any easier to return to Mars one way or the other. Can you think of something specific that can be done more easily if it misses Mars in-plane vs out?

Comment: @uhoh You could arrange for later fly-bys to at least gather *some* orbital science, *maybe* even re-try inserting instead of being out-of-plane with nowhere to go. I think I remember at least one mission could be salvaged by setting up a resonant orbit after insertion failed, but I'll have to look that up.

Comment: @Polygnome I still don't see it; I think that one is as likely to be able to do a flyby of a given planet in any plane. The spacecraft has only a small amount of delta-v that can point in any direction, so it's pretty much on fixed heliocentric ellipse no matter what the plane. Chances are low that it will pass close enough to another planet to do something, but I don't yet see why there's appreciably more phase space for this to happen if they are in vs out. I'm not saying I'm not wrong, just that I don't yet see why.

Comment: Speculation: maybe they wanted some observations of Mars’ moons as well?

Comment: @RussellBorogove The KSP guys worked it out, it's actually something under 60 degrees where raising the apoapsis to near infinity becomes the most efficient approach.

Answer (score 1):

A direct insertion into a polar orbit gives you only one option for an orbital plane: one that's initially pointed straight at the Sun.  This is sub-optimal for an observation mission, since you're more or less directly over the sunrise/sunset line, and can only see deeply shadowed ground.  It will be several months before the planet moves far enough in its orbit to give you good lighting.

If you instead capture into a highly elliptical orbit, you've got a far greater selection of orbital planes to choose from, and they're generally more useful, too.  For example, a capture burn over planetary midnight (the natural choice for something coming in from a Hohmann transfer orbit) lets you enter a polar orbit over noon, giving you a nearly-unshadowed view of the ground.

Comment: I don't really understand this, can you include a diagram or some better explanations  of or better yet sources for these assertions? *Thanks!*

Comment: I disagree, many Mars missions have utilized a "more or less directly over the sunrise/sunset line" orbit to stay sun-synchronous and always in direct view of the Sun, an example given in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/53631/40257). Scientific instruments are specifically designed with a certain orbital geometry in mind and I highly doubt (put can't prove) that they would build the spacecraft, let alone launch it, without determining exactly what the final orbit would be (re: options of orbital planes).

Comment: @BrendanLuke15, two and a half of the three main instruments on Mars Odyssey don't care about the lighting.